# Query data that have/don't have a json key - value pair

Tags: mysql, mysql-json

I am having a table in my database in which there's a field that holds data in a json format. How can I query records that have/don't have a specific key-value pair in their json?

Something like this in pseudo code

```
SELECT * FROM `foo_db`.`foo_table` 
WHERE `foo_field` IN_JSON exists('bar_key') // or IN_JSON !exists('bar_key')
```

Comment: Use something like ```WHERE JSON_OVERLAPS(column, '{"key":"value"}')```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the solutions proposed worked for me, so I had to do a lot of searching, but in the end I found something that worked for me, so posting it here

```
SELECT * FROM `foo_table`
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(`foo_field`, '$.bar_key') IS NULL / IS NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try [JSON_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) if you are looking for any string within the Json

```sql
SELECT * FROM `foo_db`.`foo_table` 
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(`foo_field`, 'one', 'bar_key') IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `JSON_CONTAINS` function.

This function takes two arguments - the JSON document to search and the key-value to look for.

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo_table
WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(foo_field, '{"bar_key": "bar_value"}');
```